# Change the amount paid per month of paypal recurring payment account

Tags: php, paypal

The situation is like this,

I have three kind of user registration on my site

1. $20/month
2. $30/month
3. $40/month

now, suppose a user registers with $30 amount and takes the 2nd registration...
next 2 months his $30 per month were deducted as per the recurring payment of paypal...working fine .:)

Now, he wants to upgrade to $40 i.e 3rd membership , so from  next month his amount deduction should be $40... How to update paypal for this change in amount..

I DON'T WANT TO GO TO PAYPAL'S SITE FOR THIS...

Is there any API for this purpose.......
Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Most sites make the user cancel the existing subscription and create a new one with the new subscription amount. I think you can only edit the amount if you setup buyer contracts where the funds are automatically withdrawn when you send a payment request to the user, but I don't know how those work. I only know about them because GoDaddy does that.

Comment: what did you do for this problem, any update?

Answer (score 2):

First off, Paypal's API is *not* a simple or easy thing to use, but what you're asking can be done.  It is simply a matter of canceling the existing 'recurring payment profile' via the API, and starting another recurring payment that ends at the same time.

The API methods themselves change depending on which system you are using.  At my company, we use Paypal Website Payments Pro.  This has a specific set of functions to perform actions.  Without knowing which system you use, however, we can't give any further advice.

The below link shows a number of the methods for the different Paypal API's.  Do your research, and try to ask specific questions.  :)

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference

Daniel Moniz

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this, but first, this caveat from PayPal should be noted:

> Note: For recurring payments with Express Checkout, the payment amount can be increased by no more than 20% every 180 days (starting when the profile is created).

Since I'm not using Express Checkout, POSTing this worked for me to change an amount from $75 to $200 (the credentials are fake):

`TRXTYPE=R&TENDER=C&PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=Acme&USER=Acme&PWD=a1b2c3d4
&ACTION=M&AMT=200.00&ORIGPROFILEID=RP0000001234`

The other caveat is that this is only one of I-don't-know-how-many APIs and I-don't-know-how-many-types-of-accounts (in this case Payflow) that PayPal has, and I don't know if something similar works for all of them. The above code is actually copied almost verbatim (credentials and amount changed) from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/recurring-billing/.