# Update Each Amount In Recurring Payments Profile of PayPal?

Tags: php, paypal

For example I have four different amount($40, $30, $20 and $10) for my product. I create a recurring profile with first amount. Now my second amount is different from first. So how can i update automatically my second amount for running recurring payment profile in **PayPal**.
I used **UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile** method. but for this we required manual running php file.
**Anyone can help me.**

Comment: i suggest you to [click here 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451666/change-the-amount-paid-per-month-of-paypal-recurring-payment-account?rq=1) and [CLICK ME2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685462/paypal-recurring-payments-with-variable-amount?rq=1)for same question that you have

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paypal Access - SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478283/paypal-access-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the amount paid per month of paypal recurring payment account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451666/change-the-amount-paid-per-month-of-paypal-recurring-payment-account)